# MarkerArray to vector

Tags: ros, rviz, ros-kinetic, python3, markerarray

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to get some information which is being published in RViz from other nodes I did not programmed.
I checked the type of messages are being post in the topics I am interested in. The one that is giving me problems is the MarkerArray type of message. I know this type have inside different Marker type. Therefore I imported both Marker and MarkerArray from visualization_msg.msgs (I am programming the node in Python, in Ubuntu 16.04). I checked the message type and I want to obtain all the position of the markers. Hence, I tried printing msg.markers.pose.position.x and msg.markers.points.x but both of them trigger the same error, msg.markers does not have that attribute. Actually it does not have any of the attributes it should but others. Those are the attributes I am getting with:

> dir(msg.markers)

```
['__add__',  '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__',       '__delitem__', '__delslice__',       '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__',       '__ge__', '__getattribute__',       '__getitem__', '__getslice__',       '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__',       '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__',      '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__',       '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__',       '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__',       '__repr__', '__reversed__',       '__rmul__', '__setattr__',       '__setitem__', '__setslice__',       '__sizeof__', '__str__',       '__subclasshook__', 'append',       'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert',    'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

Do I have to declare the markers as something else to be able to obtain those data? I know Markers are supposed to be just to print but it is the only topic with the data I need to use.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/321381/markerarray-to-vector/) by [RalLpezMartn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40816/rallpezmartn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2019-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is quite similar to #q321354, but in Python and with a different message type.

[visualization_msgs/MarkerArray](http://docs.ros.org/api/visualization_msgs/html/msg/MarkerArray.html) has a single field:

```
visualization_msgs/Marker[] markers
```

`markers` is an unbounded array (or list). For Python, those are mapped onto *tuples* (see [wiki/msg](http://wiki.ros.org/msg#Message_Description_Specification)).

> Hence, I tried printing `msg.markers.pose.position.x` and `msg.markers.points.x` but both of them trigger the same error, msg.markers does not have that attribute

If `msg` is a `MarkerArray`, you must first select one of the elements in the `markers` tuple before you can access any of the properties of that `Marker`.

So to access the second `Marker` in the `markers` tuple, you'd do:

```
msg.markers[1].pose.position.x
```

(after making sure it actually contains at least two markers, of course)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-04-18**:
And similar to #q321354, this is a Python question, not something ROS specific.

**Comment by [RalLpezMartn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40816/rallpezmartn/) on 2019-04-18**:
Well that was quick and extremely useful. Haven't work with this kind of elements ever.
That solved it perfectly, thank you so much.